# Github and Bitbuck same Server host key

Tags: ssh

I'm having some problems to use Github and Bitbucket using Git+SSH. Debuging using `ssh -vvv github.com` and `ssh -vvv bitbucket.org` I see the following output line:

```
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:KlUGRblWqoKHE/El3La1HXdxh3SdS4UCU+M456GPyIk
```

I can see the same output line when I ssh to serveo.net. In this [help page of Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) it's write that the Server host key fingerprint is `SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8`, that is different what I'm seeing in the `ssh -vvv github.com`. This mean there is something wrong at my local network?

Comment: It feels like it is definitely something wrong. But not necessarily in a local network. BTW, what is your jurisdiction?

Comment: Did you try to SSH to IPs instead of FQDNs, so you can verify you don’t have any DNS misconfiguration/ poisoning.

Comment: @marcusaurelius, yes, I tried and it didn't work. But it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @KOLANICH, It's working now. I'm not responsible to the local network. I was just trying to help guys responsible to the local network. What you mean by jurisdiction?

Comment: I mean if there any laws prescribing ISPs doing MiTM on encrypted/authenticated connections in the state where you are situated. Because recently Kazakhstan started doing that for TLS (internet users were prescribed to install a rogue root cert). And PRC is known to be doing that for ages. It is obvious that it is a matter of time when this attack will be done to other encrypted protocols.